# Solution to a certain PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

Given a 2-covariant tensor field $T$ on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, is it possible to solve the equation
$$
\nabla \alpha = T
$$
where $\alpha$ is a 1-form and $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $g$? This seems like a fundamental question but I can't find anything that touches on this at all. It would also be interesting to replace the setting with a more general affine connection $\nabla$.

For instance, it is a classical problem in differential topology (answered by de Rham cohomology) whether or not a given 1-form $\omega$ on a manifold $M$ can be written as $\omega = df$ for some function $f$. At one rank higher, we have the question of if a 2-form $\omega$ on $M$ can be written as $d\alpha$ for a 1-form $\alpha$. My question concerns the analogous scenario in the space of symmetric tensor fields, rather than antisymmetric tensor fields (differential forms). In this case, we no longer have the exterior derivative $d$, so one natural differential operator to take its place is a connection $\nabla$.

Comment: For a question like this, you should always first study the simplest possible case, which is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard flat metric. And first the cases $n = 2$ and $n=3$. After you have looked at those as best as you can, you can then start looking at Riemannian manifolds.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.

Even locally there is a problem for the solvability, let alone globally. I want to draw analogy to the exact 1-form question, that is, one rank lower to the proposed question. For a 1-form $\omega$ to have an $f$ such that
$$\nabla f = df = \omega,$$
we need a local condition $d\omega=0$, but also globally $H^1(M, R)=0$.

Here is a concrete counter example, mainly addressing the global issue. Say $M=S^2$ with the standard metric. Let $T=dv$ be the volume form. Then for a 1-form $\alpha$,
$$\nabla \alpha = T \Longrightarrow d\alpha = T.$$
The reason is that the skew-symmetrizaiton of $\nabla \alpha$, as a covariant 2-tensor, is the exterior differentiation, but $T$ is skew-symmetric already.

It is well-known such an $\alpha$ does not exist, by cohomological reasons.